# Sizing the Python standard library

Tags: python, python-3.x

I want to find out how many objects and methods there are in the standard library for a given Python 3.x installation, to compare to different languages. For this, I wrote a `script.py`.

```py
from sys import stdlib_module_names
from inspect import isclass
from importlib import import_module

modules = stdlib_module_names - {'this', 'antigravity'}

col = []
for m in modules:
    try:
        col.append(dir(import_module(m)))
    except:
        pass

col = {item for sublist in col for item in sublist}

cnt = 0
for thing in col:
    try:
        if isclass(eval(thing)):
            cnt += len(dir(thing))
    except:
        pass

print(cnt + len(col))
```

I notice `dir` is not exact, it gives different values per run.

- command line: `python script.py` gives 14075 to 14092 things,
- VSCode REPL: 1st and 2nd run are different, consequent runs are identical to 2nd.

**Questions**

1. Is this result in the ballpark of being correct?
2. Is there an invariant way to get the number of functions and methods in `stdlib_module_names`?

Answer (score 2):

> 1. Is this result in the ballpark of being correct?

No.  This code makes no sense whatsoever.  You iterate the dirs, which are all strings, and then you eval each string. Most of the time, the eval call will fail with a `NameError` which you don't see, because you `except: pass` on those. It does happen that sometimes these evals succeed when the name happens to be in the builtin namespace (e.g. "dict" or "IndexError"). But then, you're not really counting anything meaningful by accumulating `len(dir(thing))` on those builtins.

> 2. Is there an invariant way to get the number of functions and methods in `stdlib_module_names`?

Not really. I think you will get a much better result with a simple grep the source code of [cpython/Lib](https://github.com/python/cpython/tree/main/Lib) directory for "def " and "class ".